# Is the desktop gradient gone in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, appearance

I cannot figure out how to make a desktop gradient in 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04, and there it was simply in the settings, but seems to be gone in 18.04 :-(( THANKS!

Comment: Are you referring to the solid color gradient for desktop background?

Comment: yes, and PRATAP already answered this below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set any color from settings>background>background>color

[image]

I use https://www.color-hex.com/ this website for choosing colors.

then run below commands

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'horizontal'
```

you may put `'vertical'` also

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#456789'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
```

Example

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'horizontal'
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#456789'
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
pratap@pratap:~$
```

replace any color you want in above commands.

Horizontal Grading
[image]

Vertical Grading
[image: enter code here]

Comment: Hello, What if I want to factory reset these background settings back to normal?

Comment: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type`

Comment: You have to use that `reset` to number of settings you changed.