# Background image resize in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: desktop-background

Recently updated to 18.04.1 and now I cannot resize my background image from fill screen to center image.  How can I resize the image now that 18 doesnt have the quick resize feature?

Answer (score 18):

to know the current picture-option run the below command in terminal
`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options`

Example:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options
'zoom'
```

in my case, the result is 'zoom'

to know the available options for 'picture-options' run the below command in terminal
`gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options`

Example:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options
enum
'none'
'wallpaper'
'centered'
'scaled'
'stretched'
'zoom'
'spanned'
pratap@pratap:~$
```

to use the option `centered` from the available options from above range, use the below command
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'`

Example:

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
pratap@pratap:~$
```

Use as below

for Background = `org.gnome.desktop.background`
for Lock Screen = `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver`

[image]

***GUI way***

open `gnome-tweaks`.
if not yet installed, install it by the command
`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

find the options under Background and Lock Screen as `Adjustment` and choose from available.

[image]

[image]

background color can be changed with this answer as a guideline only. https://askubuntu.com/a/1090204/739431 available options are solid, gradient horizontal and gradient vertical.

[image]

Comment: This answer was asked for Ubuntu 18.04, but is still good for 20.04. Strange that the standard background-image chooser doesn't provide this option.

Comment: The `gsettings` commands still work for 22.04 also, although there is `picture-uri-dark` that must be set for the dark theme too, for example:  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file:///usr/share/my-dark-background.png"`