# How to adjust a background wallpaper?

Tags: 20.04, unity, desktop-background, appearance

Windows used to have a feature to fill, tile, center, stretch etc. a wallpaper to set in the background. I recently set a wallpaper as the background image of my Ubuntu desktop, however by default it is in "fill" format but I want it in tile. I don't see any options in the background settings to do that. I have many images that are of a phone screen size, I want to set them on my desktop too(in tile or fit). I am using the latest 20.04 version.

Comment: Have you installed Gnome Tweak Tool?  You can make the adjustments with it.  Sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111271/739431

Comment: The answer to your question can depend on what desktop environment you are using. Are you using GNOME?

Comment: @AlexFullam I don't know. I have the default 20.04 which as I'm presuming uses Gnome.

Comment: on 22.04 it's now `gnome-tweaks` but it does not have "tile" option (and lacks descriptions of the available options) - see UnKNOWn's link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background image resize in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111201/background-image-resize-in-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts)