# Wallpaper resizing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, desktop-background

Just upgraded to 22.04 but there seems to be no option for wallpaper positioning / resizing. Can you help me where can I find those settings? Not at the Background not at Appearances I can make adjustments to the wallpaper. I can only select an image but no scaling or resizing to make my custom wallpaper fit to the screen..

Thank you for your help!

Bests,
Tamas

Comment: Anyone maybe found the way to resize wallpaper in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: this could help, it has for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111201/background-image-resize-in-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts/1111271#1111271